# Singleton of Java functional interface as enum

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, singleton

While looking at the source code of the Comparators class, I came across these lines of code.

```
class Comparators {

    //...

    enum NaturalOrderComparator implements Comparator<Comparable<Object>> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public int compare(Comparable<Object> c1, Comparable<Object> c2) {
            return c1.compareTo(c2);
        }

        @Override
        public Comparator<Comparable<Object>> reversed() {
            return Comparator.reverseOrder();
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

I think I understand what this does.
It's a Singleton instance which implements the Comparator interface.
It uses the "compareTo" of classes that implement the Comparable interface for natural ordering (please correct me if I am wrong in any of this).

What I do not understand however, why is it done using an enum. I really like enums for Singletons, don't get me wrong but in this case I personally think this would have been simpler:

```
public static final Comparator<Comparable<Object>> NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR =
    new Comparator<Comparable<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Comparable<Object> c1, Comparable<Object> c2) {
            return c1.compareTo(c2);
        }

        //...

    }
```

Are there any reasons to implement this using enums aside from personal preference?

Comment: Did you forget `final` in the last declaration? Also, can you explain why you think the second option is simpler?

Comment: @ernest_k yeah the "final" got lost but it's fixed now.

Comment: @ernest_k I think my option is simpler because:

* enums inside of classes are not very common
* enums implementing interfaces are not very common
* implementing functional interfaces as enums is even more uncommon
* arguably less code
* shorter access using "NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR" instead of NaturalOrderComparator.INSTANCE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It maybe due to `Serializable`.

Based on your approach, if you create an object that holds the `Comparators.NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR`, when you write to the object and read it back, a new `NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR` will be created. Since the object cost is so small it breaks the **singleton**.

Some evidence for that is `Collections.ReverseComparator`. It uses your approach:

```
static final ReverseComparator REVERSE_ORDER = new ReverseComparator();
```

But the drawback is that the following code must be present to maintain the *singleton*

```
private Object readResolve() { return Collections.reverseOrder(); }
```

Now which one is easier? Personally, I prefer to use 'enum singleton' pattern as my first choice.

Comment: Then the question comes - why do they not do it for reverse comparator?

Comment: It's just because jdk guys not update the old pattern. I checked openjdk history, the `Collections.ReverseComparator` was added 11 years ago (may be more early). But the `Comparators.natrualOrder` is marked `@since 1.8`, it was added 5 years ago.

Comment: @Jai Perhaps the real question would be why they didn't refactor/move `ReverseComparator` when they introduced `Comparators` in java 8, but they are very reluctant to introduce change that is not strictly required.

Comment: @Hulk that is exactly the point, there are many more changes like this that *could* have been done, but they are seen as low priority... and indeed it is low

Comment: @Hulk Perhaps they are worried that someone has already serialized a `ReverseComparator` and has an implementation that actually deserialize it (???) ? Why did they even bother making it implement `Serializable` when it is `private`?

Comment: @Jai without it being `Serializable`, collections with such a comparator (like e.g. `TreeMap`) could no longer be serializable.

Comment: They did, however, adjust the `ReverseComparator` to add an implementation of the new `Comparator.reversed()`-method using the  new `Comparator.naturalOrder()`. This was the minimum change required for correctness, otherwise the default-implementation would have led to an infinite recursion due to calling `Collections.reverseOrder(this)` in turn.

Answer (score 6):

That is exactly the point in *Item 89: For instance control, prefer enum types to readResolve* from Effective Java actually and it has to do with `Serialization`.

Maintaining `readResolve` instead of the enum instance is much more complicated and cumbersome.